# Word order with "dass wenn" and "dass als"

Tags: grammar, word-order

> Ich finde, dass wenn man zu viel redet, hört man nicht genug.
>
> Ich liebe japanisches Essen sehr, dass als ich in Japan war, habe ich es jeden Tag gegessen.

Is the word order for both these sentences correct? It seems tricky to me because of the "dass wenn" and "dass als" combinations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's a subordinate clause within a subordinate clause, and in both clauses the verb comes last.

For the first sentence, the possible choices are:

```
Ich finde, dass, wenn man zu viel redet, man nicht genug hört.
Ich finde, dass man, wenn man zu viel redet, nicht genug hört.
Ich finde, dass man nicht genug hört, wenn man zu viel redet.
```

For the second sentence, you get analogously:

```
Ich liebe japanisches Essen so sehr, dass, als ich in Japan war, ich es jeden Tag gegessen habe.
Ich liebe japanisches Essen so sehr, dass ich es, als ich in Japan war, jeden Tag gegessen habe.
Ich liebe japanisches Essen so sehr, dass ich es jeden Tag gegessen habe, als ich in Japan war.
```

Comment: Is there actually a (non-stilistical) limit of nested relative clausules? "*Ich finde, dass, wenn Günther, der Nachbarn, der jüngst angekommen ist, zu viel redet, man  ihn gar nicht verstehen kann.*" Stilistically sounds awful, but, are ther grammaticaly *allowed*? Or the prohibition of those sentences is just by "no body would say it like that".

Comment: @c.p. if you can keep track of your current position in the sentence, infinite nesting of relative clauses is allowed. But after the third level, even most native speakers begin to lose the sense of the sentence. Even more so in hearing than in reading.

Comment: Everybody loves "Hypotaxe" / hypotaktische Satzkonstruktionen: `Derjenige, der denjenigen, der den Pfahl, der an der Brücke, die an der Straße, die nach Mainz führt, liegt, stand, umgeworfen hat, anzeigt, erhält eine Belohnung. (Eine Belohnung erhält derjenige, der denjenigen anzeigt, der den Pfahl umgeworfen hat, der an der Brücke stand, die an der Straße liegt, die nach Mainz führt.`

Comment: @Vogel612 I guess infinite nesting isn't allowed, but arbitrarily deep nesting is allowed. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see a problem, if you are disposed to reorder:

> Wenn man zu viel redet, hört man nicht genug, finde ich.

As for the second,

> Ich liebe japanisches Essen so sehr, dass ich es jeden Tag gegessen habe, als ich in Japan war.

Or, if you don't mind to nominalize a little:

> Ich liebe japanisches Essen so sehr, dass ich es täglich wärend meines Aufenthaltes in Japan gegessen habe.

Comment: Your two first suggestions are fine, only one point to mention: "finde ich" is better in written form, when spoken this will be automatically shortened. The third is too free, I find.